# Can a COM Object have a "fake" CLSID?

Tags: windows, security, com, activex, clsid

Example: I have an ActiveX object (.cab file) in my "Downloaded Program Files" folder. Using a program like HiJackThis, I find that the CLSID of that object is:

```
1D4DB7D2-6EC9-47A3-BD87-1E41684E07BB
```

I have been told that I can 'google' that CLSID to see if this is a malicious ActiveX object. For example, if I google that CLSID, I find an article that states this CLSID belongs to a malicious program: http://www.systemlookup.com/O16/595-FunWebProducts.html

Here is my question: **Is it possible to compile a "fake" CLSID into a COM object?**

For example, could I create a malicious ActiveX object, and give it the CLSID of a legitimate native Windows COM object?

Also, is there any other way a malicious COM object could "hide behind" a "legitimate" CLSID?

Comment: Yes but they can't coexist (a COM object is uniquely identified by its ID) then applications that rely on such COM object will be broken and your malicious trick discovered.

Comment: So, in theory, the only way I could truly "mask" the malicious app would be to first write my own COM object that mimics a legitimate one, like Adobe Flash, then add my own malicious code on top of that. Which obviously would be a lot of work, especially considering that a signature-based file scanner would be able to detect that my COM object's signature does not match what it's supposed to be. So it would be extremely impractical to go through all the effort, unless you weren't worried about apps that use the legit COM object crashing, of course. Even then, the antivirus **should** catch it.

Comment: Yes, moreover Windows will detect that for its own components and applications installed with Windows Installer may also detect they've been corrupted and be repaired automatically. Finally you can't update files in use so...no, you can't really hide a "virus" in that way (it'll make it even more visible).

Comment: Hmya, why didn't thousands of virus hackers think of this before?  Review Raymond Chen's blog for the phrase "airtight hatchway" and what being on the wrong side of it means.